# how to make an arrayList of objects from another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 classes and I want to make an object in each of them to control the other

for example, I am asked to do:

> Generates a model of a Candy with the specified number of candies.

I am going to do that in class B, but the Candy is in a seperate class

```
public Candy(String CompanyName, String ProducerName) throws TeamException{

This.CandyProducer = ProducerName;
This.CandyCompany = CompanyName;}
```

Now I know I can do:

```
Candy FirstCandy = new Candy(KitKat, Stephen);
```

to create an object in the class Candy.

But what I want is to have 5 objects of the class Candy.

I tried doing:

```
List<Candy> CandyModel = ArrayList<Candy>(numOfCandies);
```

but it did not work, because I can't assign the "CompanyName", and "ProducerName" for any of the candies in the ArrayList.

Any tips ?

Comment: The question seems unclear. Please try being more precise!

Comment: Have a `for` loop, create candies in `for` loop, add them in the `List<Candy>`. If the size is known before hand, you can use `Candy[] candies` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also u miss new keyword while creating array list there..

```
Candy FirstCandy = new Candy("KitKat", "Stephen");
Candy SecondCandy = new Candy("KitKat", "Stephen");
Candy ThirdCandy = new Candy("KitKat", "Stephen");

List<Candy> CandyModel =new ArrayList<Candy>();

CandyModel.add(FirstCandy);
CandyModel.add(SecondCandy);
CandyModel.add(ThirdCandy);
```

an you can iterate it using listIterator or iterator somthing like this

```
ListIterator<Candy> itr=CandyModel.listIterator();  
System.out.println("traversing elements in forward direction...");  
while(itr.hasNext()){  
System.out.println(itr.next());  
}
```

Comment: List<Candy> CandyModel = Arrays.asList(new Candy(KitKat, Stephen), new Candy(snickers, Bob),...); could work too

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to add newly created `Candy` objects  to your list

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCandies; i++) {
    CandyModel.add(new Candy("Company" + i, "Producer" + i));
}
```

The `ArrayList` constructor creates an empty list which you need to populate with objects. The parameter in the constructor is an "expected size" or "initial internal capacity" that the list will grow to but it won't make any logical difference.